# Where are Vita saves stored?

Tags: ps-vita

I want to borrow some Vita games off a friend, I was wondering if I might need to worry about overwriting his own saves.

With PS3/PSP games I know saves are stored on the device itself (since the game media is read only), but since Vita has its games on memory cards, are the saves on the game media itself? (like GB/DS games)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is that it depends on the specific game.

From the [PS Vita manual](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/psvita/game/game_card.html):

> Two types of games are stored on PS Vita cards. One type saves data on the PS Vita card and the other type saves data on the memory card for the PS Vita system. To determine which is the case for a specific game, see the software manual for the game.

If you want details for a specific game, a lot of publishers now put their manuals online.

Comment: If a game saves on the game card itself, can you backup the save off it and restore it afterwards?

Comment: @JohnoBoy No, you can't back up off a Vita card.

Comment: Added note on this. If you have save game data on a digital download copy of a game and delete that game, you may also loose the save files. You can avoid this by backing up the game via the Content Manager before deleting.